# How can i connecting two different web forms in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, webforms

I'm working on my school project in which I need to build up one original web application. But I got an error when I tried to connect two web forms in my project. I have no idea what's wrong about it, and I have looked at many video instruction sources showing how to do it, and still I have the same error.
Here is what I have done.

First, I created a web from and named it `MainForm`
and also I made another one and named `TestForm1`.
Then, I put a button on TestForm1 aspx file, double-clicked the button to call the cs file, and there I coded

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainForm newWindow = new MainForm();
    newWindow.Show();
}
```

Here, an error comes up and I see a red line under "Show"
The error says

> MainFor1 does not contain a definition for "Show," and no extension
>   method accepting a first argument of type "MainForm" could be found.

What is wrong about my code? I just simply made two forms and am trying to connect them.
Please tell me how I can handle this problem.

Sorry for my bad English, since I'm not a native speaker.
And Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're mixing up web forms and Windows forms. You cannot `Show()` web forms.

Comment: A form definition looks like this : public partial class Form1 : Form.  It inherits the 'Form' class.  You are probably missing the inheritance which will have the Show() method.

Comment: You can't use `Show()`, you can call   `Server.Transfer("TestForm1.aspx", true);`

Comment: OH, as you guys say I was mixing up Windows Forms and Web Forms. Thank you so much for saving me from the deep chaos, I really feel embarrassed for having such a low level trouble. Thank you everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

According to my Understating you want to navigate to another page, you can add a link button to take you to the other page like so:

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button" PostBackUrl="anotherpage.aspx" />
```

Comment: I found I was mistaking webforms and windows forms. Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

To show a new Page (not a Form!) means that you want the Web Browser to open a new URL. This can be done in many ways, and the way closest to your orignal code is this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("MainForm.aspx");
}
```

A `Redirect` literally tells the browser: please go to another URL. The browser then makes a new http request with the new URL, and the server then shows that page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Server.Transfer()`, method `Show()` can't be used in WebForms. Probably You are wrong WinFroms with WebForms.

```
  Server.Transfer("TestForm1.aspx", true);
```

Here you find [introduction to ASP.NET and Web Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973868.aspx)

> Summary: This article explains how Web Forms are fundamental to Microsoft ASP.NET, shows how to build a Web form, and discusses the controls essential for building a Web Form. (16 printed pages)
>
> Objectives
>
> - Learn about Web Forms
> - Learn the Web controls that are built into Web Forms
> - Build a Web Form